# dialog.show() crashed InputMethodService?

Tags: java, android

Sorry for bothering again, but in my Android keyboard I have

```
public class zyz extends InputMethodService 
implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

    private LinearLayout mInputView;

    @Override public View onCreateInputView() {
        mInputView = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, null);
        AddKeys("/layout.txt");
        return mInputView;
    }

... 

final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this,R.style.myBackgroundStyle);
...    

linLayBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

...
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
dialog.show();
...
```

Which is supposed to show a dialog when a button is presses. Yet it crashes the application...

```
08-30 17:04:41.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15712): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks!

dialog.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/layout_root"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/frame_left" android:id="@+id/frameLeft"></ImageView>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@drawable/frame_center" android:id="@+id/LLdialog4letter">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/bun_r" android:id="@+id/ivDialogLetter" android:layout_marginTop="3px" android:layout_marginRight="9px" android:layout_marginLeft="9px"></ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/frame_right" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/frameRight"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show the code how do you reference the context, how do you instnatiate the dialog.....

Comment: Try inflating the layout you want to set in `setContentView()`

Comment: Didn't really understand... I need a dialog to pop out, when a button is hit.

Comment: Inflate the layout R.layout.dialog before you do `dialog.setContentView()` or use AlertDialog

Comment: you mean like that - LinearLayout di = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
dialog.setContentView(di);
dialog.show(); - gives the same error.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3003/discussion-between-roger-and-nikola-despotoski)

Answer (score 2):

This will work for you Enjoy

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                 builder.setTitle("Make your selection");
                 builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                 {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item)
                    {
                       // Do something with the selection
                    }
                 });
                 AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                 Window window = alert.getWindow();
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = window.getAttributes();
                 lp.token = mInputView.getWindowToken();
                 lp.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_ATTACHED_DIALOG;
                 window.setAttributes(lp);
                 window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
                 alert.show();
```

Comment: What is `mInputView` in this context?

Comment: The input text view that is triggering the keyboard.